# Can I define time limit for one function in PHP?

Tags: php, time-limiting

I'm making module for a PHP ecommerce system. This system database have a 2000 products. I need to update all products(some values) in a one day. I dont want to update all products one time.

I try update every period 100 products when the visitor open some page (module is hooked init - header). Here i want to give time limit. If this 100 product don't update in 20 seconds make break and write last updated product id to database.

How can I do this? How this function know 20 seconds later break?

Comment: time() at start and in the loop

Comment: Why are you doing this on user interaction and not in e.g. a cron? Also, updating a mere 2000 products I don't feel should take anything like 20 seconds, let alone for only 100.

Comment: Yes i can use time() in a loop, is this not problem for a server?

Comment: @JonStirling This is a module for ecommerce system. I was try give a cronjob information but here all users don't know how to make a cronjob.

Comment: @user5510975 call time() 1000 times an look to time of execution. I think it will be small

Comment: 20 seconds to update 100 records sounds like your query is doing rather a lot of extra work and needs to be examined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set time limit for the whole PHP script. So you can move out this function to separate script, set time limit there and run it as sub-process.

I recommend using Symfony Process component (can be used without Symfony):
http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/process.html

Using it you can even set time limit from your main process:
http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/process.html#process-timeout

Comment: This is what I need but its Symfony component. How can i use without  symfony? (Thanks)

Comment: `composer require symfony/process`

Comment: If you cannot use composer, you can download it from https://github.com/symfony/process

Comment: or use php function `proc_open` directly - http://blog.dubbelboer.com/2012/08/24/execute-with-timeout.html

Comment: execute-with-timeout.html will be help to me. Thank you.